# TypeError: conv2d(): argument ‘input’ (position 1) must be Tensor, not PackedSequence

Tags: sequence, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I'm trying to apply a conv2d layer to a batch of sequence data where the sequences don't have the same length. I tried passing a packed sequence but that doesn't work...

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 5)

x = torch.randn([16,1580,201]) # Where x has dimensions (batch*sequence*feats)
lengths = torch.tensor(
    [1580, 959, 896, 881, 881, 881, 881, 881, 881, 881, 881, 881, 881, 335, 254, 219]
) 
# So only the first element in the batch has size 1580, the rest have been padded

x_pack = torch.nn.utils.rnn.pack_padded_sequence(x, lengths, batch_first=True)

x_pack = conv1(x_pack)
print(x_pack)

# ... then feed x_pack to an LSTM...
```

Does anyone know how to not apply the convolution on the padded values of the inputs? will I have to iterate though each element of the batch?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please make your code self-contained? A minimal, runnable example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Jatentaki I've modified the code to make it a runnable example and added some details. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still unclear to me what you're trying to do. You define a `Conv2d` which maps from 1 feature map to 16 feature maps, with size of 5. How would you want to apply it to data which has no spatial dimensions? I'm thinking there is some misconception (rather than purely implementational issues) on your side, but I cannot figure out which. Don't you actually mean to apply a 1d convolution along the time (sequence) dimension?

Comment: The problem is analogous to a batch of greyscale images with variable width. You'd have a (batch, 1, max_width, height) and want to pass it to a 5x5 conv2d with one input channel and 16 filters (i.e. nn.Conv2d(1, 16, 5)). I was just wondering if given the fact that these images had variable width could I pass the batch to the conv layer as a packed padded sequence but it doesn't seem like it.

I've managed to solve this by simply keeping track of how the sequence lengths (or the "widths") change after passing through the conv layer and masking out the results. Thanks anyway @Jatentaki!

Comment: Ok, because your `x` has only 3 dimensions (so it cannot possibly be `batch, feature, width, height`), so I was confused. Yes, the approach you're taking is likely the best possible and, AFAIK, packed sequences do effectively the same.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right I forgot to add a x.unsqueeze(1) in the example my bad! And thanks again.